# Unable to attach the certificate from a keyvault in a different subscription to an app service

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

The app service is in subscription1 and the keyvault is in subscription2, I want to attach the certificate in the keyvault to the appservice during the terraform deployment and I keep getting the error Error: Unable to determine the Resource ID for the Key Vault at URL "https://.vault.azure.net/"

If I skip the certificate and secret data source, and use the keyvault_secret_id, I get the error that Code="Forbidden" Message="Client address is not authorized and caller is
not a trusted service.

This is the below code:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kvprod" {
  provider            = azurerm.<alias>
  name                = "<keyvaultname>"
  resource_group_name = "<keyvaultrgname>"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "kvcertificate" {
  provider     = azurerm.<alias>
  name         = "<certifinatename>"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kvprod.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvsecret" {
  provider     = azurerm.<alias>
  name         = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.kvcertificate.name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kvprod.id
}

 resource "azurerm_app_service_certificate" "certificate" { 
  name                = "<certifinatename>"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.<appservicerg>.location 
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.<appservicerg>.name
  pfx_blob            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv.value
  #key_vault_secret_id = "<keyvaultID>"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling Azure Key Vault Firewall with Azure DevOps - what is the best way when the KV is in a different subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72154997/enabling-azure-key-vault-firewall-with-azure-devops-what-is-the-best-way-when)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to do is to ad app service principal to key vault policy

```
data "azuread_service_principal" "web_app_resource_provider" {
  application_id = "abfa0a7c-a6b6-4736-8310-5855508787cd"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "web_app_resource_provider" {
  key_vault_id            = module.key_vault.key_vault_id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azuread_service_principal.web_app_resource_provider.id
  secret_permissions      = ["Get"]
  certificate_permissions = ["Get"]
}
```

That beeing said you will get another error

```
Error: Unable to determine the Resource ID for the Key Vault at URL
```

It seems that terraform is unable to create app service cert in diffrent resource group and subsciprtion.