# Enabling Azure Key Vault Firewall with Azure DevOps - what is the best way when the KV is in a different subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

Enabling Azure Key Vault Firewall with Azure DevOps - what is the best way when the KV is in a different subscription ?

- The requirement is to attach the ssl certificate from the keyvault to an app service.
- When the pipeline was run, it always shows the Azure Build Agent doesn't have access and the error is [ StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403
  Code="Forbidden" Message="Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service. InnerError={"code":"ForbiddenByFirewall"} )

Is there a way to best achieve this? We cannot allow all the MS build agent IPs.

Comment: Hi devopsseeker; can I ask, how exactly are you trying to attach the certificate to the app service?

Comment: Did you try to explore Self hosted agents instead, because keyvault is firewall protected and might have selected VNETs traffic?

Comment: A different subscription than **what**? Azure DevOps isn't in a subscription. Are you talking about your build agents? If so, are they self-hosted agents or Microsoft hosted agents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't archive this with default agent pool. You must use self-hosted agent in your Azure tenant as VM or scale-set, then you can configure firewall and even use KV in private network. More here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops for scale-set, above this link you can find how to install agent on single VM (Linux or Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Since it is required to create a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal) in order to grant the pipeline [access to the Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you can simply provided the same principal privileges to update your firewall settings in the `Access Control (IAM)` pane of KeyVault's page in the Azure portal, and temporarily add the agents IP address to the Key Vault's Firewall white list, like so:

```yaml
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Add devops host ip address
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "MyAzureSubscription"
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        agent_ip=$(curl -s http://ipinfo.io/json | jq -r '.ip')
        az keyvault network-rule add --name MyKeyVault --resource-group MyResourceGroup --ip-address $agent_ip

  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: Load Secret from Key Vault
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "MyAzureSubscription"
      KeyVaultName: "MyKeyVault"
      SecretsFilter: "*"
      # If this is true, then it will run before the ip address is whitelisted
      RunAsPreJob: false 

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Remove devops host ip address (Clean up)
    # this ensures that the firewall is cleaned up, even if a prior task fails:
    condition: always()
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "MyAzureSubscription"
      scriptType: "bash"
      scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
      inlineScript: |
        agent_ip=$(curl -s http://ipinfo.io/json | jq -r '.ip')
        az keyvault network-rule remove --name MyKeyVault --resource-group MyResourceGroup --ip-address $agent_ip
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and as I can see we have few alternatives:

- self-hosted agent - you have your own Virtual Machine with agents that is connected to your Azure DevOps organization and then, since VM has public IP you can whitelist this IP in your Key Vault - quite a lot of effort to setup the VM but gives a lot of flexibility
- whitelisting all the [IP addresses of Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents) - my least favourite one
- whitelisting particular IP during the pipeline execution as described by Panu Oksala in [How to Access Restricted Azure Key Vault from Azure DevOps](https://oksala.net/2023/02/12/how-to-access-restricted-azure-key-vault-from-azure-devops/) - the one I like the most in a simple scenario, for large number of pipelines I would go with the first option